# VS Code: how to be warned of missing functions?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Using flake8 as my linter, if I write some Python code that references a non-existent function in the same file, VS Code flags it up as an undefined variable. However, if I try to reference a non-existent function in a class, it doesn't. For example:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        return

one = Foo()
one.bar()  # No warning
one.foo()  # No warning either!
```

doesn't generate any warnings against the `one.foo()` line.

Is there a setting I need to change in the VS Code Python extension to get this to work or is it a limitation of the system?

Edited to make it clear that I was using flake8. All of the suggested solutions mention pylint which does work. I'm still interested in whether or not this can work with flake8 but pylint is working for me as an alternative.

Comment: Does it raise `AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'foo'`?

Comment: With pylint setup and enabled (default settings), your code outputs the warning ``"Instance of 'Foo' has no 'foo' member"`` in my VS Code environment. Maybe you do not yet have setup a linter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set [pylint](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting) and yo will have it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was using flake8 (which I should have been clearer about in my question - I'll edit it) and either that linter doesn't have this capability or I need to find a setting to enable it or it doesn't like my file layout. pylint seems to catch the problem I was having so I'll go with that for now.